# Discrete Operator Approximating Partial Derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

Suppose I have $u_{m}$ as a infinite vector. Then the central difference operator $\delta_{0}u_{m}= \frac{u_{m+1}-u_{m-1}}{2h}$ . What is ($\delta_{0})^{2} u_{m}$? Find the order of approximation to ($\delta_{0})^{2} u_{m} - u_{xx}$.

So I found $(\delta_{0})^{2} u_{m}$ = $\delta_{0}(\delta_{0}u_{m})$ = $\delta_{0}w_{m}$ = $\frac{w_{m+1}-w_{m-1}}{2h}$ = $\frac{\frac{u_{m+2}-u_{m}}{2h} - \frac{u_{m}-u_{m-2}}{2h}}{2h}$ = $\frac{u_{m+2}-2u_{m}+u_{m-2}}{4h^{2}}$

Then to compute ($\delta_{0})^{2} u_{m} - u_{xx}$ =  $\frac{u_{m+2}-2u_{m}+u_{m-2}}{4h^{2}} - u_{xx}$ I need to expand each $u_{m+2}$ and $u_{m-2}$ using Taylor's Theorem, but when doing so I obtain

($\delta_{0})^{2} u_{m} - u_{xx}$ =  $\frac{u_{m+2}-2u_{m}+u_{m-2}}{4h^{2}} - u_{xx}$ = $u_{xx} + O(h^2)$ but I think the $u_{xx}$ should have canceled. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Without your detailed computations we cannot say. Indeed, the term $u_{xx}$ should have disappeared. My bet is that you forgot the factor $\frac 12$ in the Taylor development $f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x)+ \frac 12 h^2 f''(x)+O(h^3)$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I am sorry, I should have posted my calculation. This is my first time on Math Stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

$$u_{m+2} = u_m + 2h u_x(x_m) + \frac 12 (2h)^2 u_{xx}(x_m)+\frac16 (2h)^3 u_{xxx}(x_m)+O(h^4),\\
u_{m-2} = u_m - 2h u_x(x_m) + \frac 12 (2h)^2 u_{xx}(x_m)-\frac16 (2h)^3 u_{xxx}(x_m)+O(h^4),$$
hence

$$u_{m+2}-2u_{m}+u_{m-2}   =  {u_m + 2h u_x(x_m) + \frac 12 (2h)^2 u_{xx}(x_m)+\frac16 (2h)^3 u_{xxx}(x_m)+O(h^4)+u_m - 2h u_x(x_m) + \frac 12 (2h)^2 u_{xx}(x_m)-\frac16 (2h)^3 u_{xxx}(x_m)+O(h^4)-2u_m}$$

$$ =  {   \frac 12 (2h)^2 u_{xx}(x_m) O(h^4)+ \frac 12 (2h)^2 u_{xx}(x_m) +O(h^4)} = 4h^2 u_{xx}(x_m)+O(h^4).$$

Comment: I see, I left off a $\frac{1}{2}(2h)^2u_{xx}(x_{m})O(h^{4})$ term, so when I subtracted I was left with an $u_{xx}$ term. Thanks.